# Redirecting to different page on Postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC4 project, i have one layout view with form which is posting to `ContactForm` in `HomeController`.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ContactForm", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
      --actual form content goes here
   <input id="submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="pull-right" />
}
```

In my `ContactForm` action method i am again redirecting to `Index` action method where in the method I do a redirection to home page.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ContactForm(ContactModel model)
{
    try
    {
       --code goes here
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       --code goes here
    }
  return Index();
  //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

But the problem is that it is not redirecting to Home Page instead it is redirecting to `ContactForm` action method under `HomeController`

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return Redirect("www.homepage.com");
}
```

Comment: After a user enter information in contact form and you submit the form, you want to redirect them to the home page? Why not just do `return RedirectToAction("HomePageAction", "HomePageController")` instead of return Redirect("www.homepage.com");?

Comment: Thanks, i tried that too, see my commented code in the question.

Comment: MVC does not have a postback

Comment: If you keep the default route with values `defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}` why are you using Redirect("www.homepage.com"); THis is the part which I do not understand. If this is not the case what is the routing configuration that you use?

Comment: @HuseinRoncevic, Then by default it will take `Home/Index` right ?

Comment: Yes, it should take you to that page.